# Проблема при установке шаблона OpenCart (QuickStart)

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

Здравствуйте!

У меня при установке шаблона вылезает вот такая ерундовина:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У приятеля установка проходит успешно, с чем это может быть связано?

(На хостинг тоже заливается с такой ошибкой) Апач, мускул и пхп версии одинаковые.)

Comment: Ну пишут же - отсутствует таблица `magaz.oc_address`. Не развернулась полностью структура, базы данных или какого дополнения... Бывает. Или дамп неполный. Или версии не совпадают. Или барабашка. И есть ещё сто причин.

Comment: @Akina Но он сохраняет все это дело в базу данных: http://imgur.com/a/iCbHL

Comment: Но сайт не создается при этом, снова кидает в инсталл